# How to change action bar color like Google Play store

Tags: android

I am trying to set action bar color like google play store.

Following code try but get exactly like play store.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
     R.drawable.testresult);
    bar = getSupportActionBar();

    Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
            Palette.Swatch vibrant = palette.getVibrantSwatch();
            if (vibrant != null) {
                // If we have a vibrant color
                // update the title TextView
                bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(vibrant
                        .getRgb()));

                // titleView.setBackgroundColor(
                // vibrant.getRgb());
                // titleView.setTextColor(
                // vibrant.getTitleTextColor());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Action bar Transparent Background.
[image]

Scroll
[image]

[image]

Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for that i found one library may helps you

> https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/FadingActionBar

and thanks to ManuelPeinado who is author of this library :)

Comment: Download samples-stock code and run application get Null Pointer  at com.manuelpeinado.fadingactionbar.FadingActionBarHelperBase.createScrollView(FadingActionBarHelperBase.java:242)

Comment: The status bar has a solid colour in that, I want the image in the status background also and solid colour after that when action bar changes its colour.

Answer (score 3):

Action bar Up navigation can be enabled by calling setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) method on to action bar. By calling this function a back arrow will be displayed on the action bar.

```
   //get action bar   
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 
    // Enabling Up / Back navigation
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

To apply background color of actionbar use setBackgroundDrawable() method and pass ColorDrawable Instance as follows:

```
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FCFCFC")));
```

hope this will help you